# Elasticsearch Nest SDK Accepts Query with Invalid JSON?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am using the Nest SDK to produce queries to Elasticsearch and am confused by what appears to be invalid JSON getting accepted by the Elasticsearch server.

My Query generation code is as follows:

```
protected SearchRequest testSearchRequest()
{
    QueryContainer MyFilter = new QueryContainer();

    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    foreach (string s in strings)
    {
        MyFilter = MyFilter || new TermQuery { Field = s, Value = "value_" + s };
    }

    return new SearchRequest("index-1,index-2")
    {
        From = 0,
        Size = 10,
        Query = new TermQuery { Field = "test", Value = "testvalue" } && MyFilter
    };
}
```

I am debugging the Request in two ways as I thought it might have been a problem getting the request data, both the `DebugInformation` property on the Search Result and the `result.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes` value show the same result:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "test": {
              "value": "testvalue"
            }
          },
          {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "a": {
                    "value": "value_a"
                  }
                },
                {
                "term": {
                  "b": {
                    "value": "value_b"
                  }
                },
                {
                "term": {
                  "c": {
                    "value": "value_c"
                  }
                },
                {
                "term": {
                  "d": {
                    "value": "value_d"
                  }
                },
                {
                "term": {
                  "e": {
                    "value": "value_e"
                  }
                }
            ]
          }
      ]
    },
    "size": 10
  }
}
```

It seems to me that the Terms generated by my loop are incorrectly being parsed with extra square brackets and invalid braces?

What is strange is that I get a `HealthyResponse` from Elasticsearch.

If I try using this string in the Kibana console it states that this is an invalid request.

Comment: Just tested against NEST 7.3.1 and the request body looks good to me for your example. Which version of NEST do you use?

Comment: This is 7.0.1 - I'm in the process of setting up 7.3.1 now - will report back shortly

Comment: `7.0.1` works fine for me as well. Maybe you can share `client.Search(..)` part as well? Maybe there is something happening after executing `testSearchRequest` method?

Comment: The query looks fine to me. The `must` and `should` clauses of a `bool` query accept an array of queries. Did you see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html ?